# subgroup generated by a permutation

Tags: permutations

For instance, if I take the permutation $\alpha=(123)(67)(458) \in S_{10}$, what is the subgroup generated by it?
Knowing that the order of $\alpha$ is 6, I already calculated $\alpha ^0, \alpha ^1$ and so on, until $\alpha ^5$.
How do I proceed from this?

Comment: It seems you have calculated every element of the subgroup then. Namely $\alpha^0,\alpha^1,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4, \alpha^5$.

Comment: Is that all I need to do?

Comment: Yes those all the elements that form the subgroup generated by $\alpha$. You can check that they really form a subgroup if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Because your permutation has order $6$
you have found all the elements of subgroup generated by $\alpha$. The subgroup is $\langle \alpha \rangle = \{\alpha^0 = id, \alpha^1, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \alpha^4, \alpha^5\}$. It's an easy exercise (if you don't see it right away) to verify this really is a subgroup.

It's maybe worth to check that your permutation really has order 6. You can see that noting that $lcm(3,2,3) = 6$ (Those numbers $3,2,3$ are length of each cycle in $\alpha$).

Comment: Thank you.
And yeah, I used the least common divisor result to say that $\alpha$ has order 6.